# Symmetrical form

Tags: css, reactjs, forms

have problem with Css. Id like to set this form symmetricaly. Buttons would be in 1 column, textfields would be in 1 column also question mark i like to have it in 1 column.

Sorry for maybe bad ticket structure here. This is the second one in my life :) Im using React.js + Styled components

[Design of the form atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5AlE.png)

```css
const ItemText = styled.div `
    padding-top: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;

    .form-inline {  
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        align-items: center;
      }
      
      .form-inline label {
        margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
      }

      .form-inline input {
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;  
      }
      
      .form-inline button {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      .form-inline button:hover {
        background-color: royalblue;
      }
      
      @media (max-width: 800px) {
        .form-inline input {
          margin: 10px 0;
        }
        
        .form-inline {
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: stretch;
        }
      }
```

```html
<ItemText>
        <div className="App">
            {
                print? <h1>{dataWhen}</h1> :null
            }
            <div className="form-inline">
                <label className="question">WHEN?</label>
                <input className="webflow-style-input" type="text" placeholder="Sem piš" onChange ={getData}/>
                <button type="submit" onClick={() => setPrint(true)}> Odeslat</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ItemText>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap your label inside a div with a fixed width

Then the length of your label won't change the placement of the other elements